# Solving the initial value problem for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Let consider the initial value problem given by $$xu_y-yu_x=u\quad\text{with}\ u(x,0)=h(x).$$ The answer that my teacher put on our exercises is $u=h(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})e^{\arctan(y/x)}$.

How I get the answer? I made some computations here and I find $$u=h\left(\frac{x^2-y^2}{x}\right)e^{y/x}.$$ Probably I'm wrong, but I can't see how to obtain the desired answer. Appreciate any help! :D

**Remark:** If someome wants to see my computations, I can put it here later.

Comment: Method of characteristics seems like the best bet by far, either by fully solving the characteristics or merely using the characteristic equations to spot a sensible change of variables.

Comment: Also, one thing to notice is that your teacher's advertised solution isn't continuous over the entire plane. That's not really an error on their part, but it does mean that one has to qualify the desired domain of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

General solution of pde is
$$u=F(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})e^{\arctan\frac{y}{x}}$$
Then solution of initial value problem is
$$u=h(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})e^{\arctan\frac{y}{x}}$$

In polar coordinates $$x=r\cos\phi,\quad y=r\sin\phi$$ pde is
$$\frac{\partial u(r,\phi)}{\partial\phi}=u(r,\phi)$$
with solution
$$u=F(r)e^\phi$$
If substitute $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $\phi=\arctan\frac{y}{x}$ we get general solution.